# Use text both as Safetext and in url in Django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I want to convert the string `[[w'ord]]` into the link `<a href="example.com?q=w'ord">w'ord</a>`

Since input can be anything, I want to make it safe by applying `conditional_escape` (so, before making link I apply `conditional_escape` and string becomes `[[w&#39;ord]]`).

But in this case `'` becomes unapplicable for the link because of the ampersand.

How can make the word safe for the html output and safe in the link?

Thank you.

Comment: keep an escaped copy and a raw copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`django.utils.http.urlquote`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlquote) for the URL and [`django.utils.html.conditional_escape`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.conditional_escape) for the link text:

```
>>> from django.utils.http import urlquote
>>> from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
>>> urlquote("w'ord")
'w%27ord'
>>> conditional_escape("w'ord")
'w&#39;ord'
```